# CSS hover preudoclass is applied during brush for elements below brush pane in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, d3.js

let me describe an issue:
I have a bar chart, each bar has :hover pseudoclass, and a d3.svg.brush() tool on that chart, which is enabled optionally. The problem is that when brush is used, changing extent or dragging it, the bars below brush extent react on mouseover and :hover pseudoclass is applied. The problem is reproduced only in FF, in Chrome everything is correct.

```
Visit  <http://jsfiddle.net/3HL4a/575/> for test..
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to attach your code to the question ideally it should be a runnable snippet or a jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes, @RobertLongson, I've updated description

Comment: I don't see what the testcase is trying to demonstrate. Nothing seems to change on hover anywhere.

Comment: In firefox, make a brush selection, then try to drag a brush green rectangle, and during dragging the bars below cursor become orange.

Comment: How do you make a brush seection? How do you drag a brush green rectangle?